# explode function retrun empty value at the 0th index of the array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$string="kk-001/kk-002";
$array=explode("kk-",$string);
```

it returns

```
Array(
    [0]=>",
    [1]=>'001/',
    [2]->'002'
)
```

but I need `001` in `index[0]` and `002` in `index[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is just as you describe,then it may be better to first remove the `kk-` parts and then explode on the `/`...

```
$string="kk-001/kk-002";
$array=explode("/",str_replace("kk-", "", $string));
print_r($array);
```

gives.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 001
    [1] => 002
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` with the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to remove empty empty values like so:

```
$string = "kk-001/kk-002";
$array = preg_split('/\/?kk\-/', $string , -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
```

**Output**:

```
Array ( [1] => 001 [2] => 002 )
```